# Variance for linear combination of coefficients

Tags: probability, variance

Why does:

> $Var(aX)=a^2Var(X)$
>
> and
>
> $Var(aX\pm bY)=a^2var(X)+b^2var(Y)\pm 2ab Cov(X,Y)$?

I've looked at similar stackexchange links, but haven't been able to find a "simple" answer without extensive math proof.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use the definition of Variance expanding

$$\mathbb{V}[aX+bY]=\mathbb{E}[(aX+bY)^2]-(\mathbb{E}[aX+bY])^2$$

$$\mathbb{E}[a^2X^2+2abXY+b^2Y^2]-a^2\mathbb{E}^2[X]-b^2\mathbb{E}^2[Y]-2ab\mathbb{E}[X]\mathbb{E}[Y]$$

Using linearity of the expectation and re-organizing the addends you get

$$a^2[\mathbb{E}(X^2)-\mathbb{E}^2(X)]+b^2[\mathbb{E}(Y^2)-\mathbb{E}^2(Y)]+2ab[\mathbb{E}(XY)-\mathbb{E}(X)\mathbb{E}(Y)]$$

Now you are almost done

---

$X$ and $Y$ are rv's thus Capital letters are needed

The second statement is valid also for $V(X-Y)$ thus I amended it.

Comment: Thanks. I figured out $a^2var(x)$ from your formula. Where does $+2ab$ come from in the second?

Comment: @hehemath : I will edit the answer with all the passages. Since you're new here, I would like to encourage you to click the check mark if this answer was helpful for you. It'll encourage others to answer your questions in the future

Comment: Thanks. Will do.

Comment: @hehemath : answer edited

Comment: Thanks. I'm unsure of how you get $2abXY$ in your second line of working? What am I missing here.

Comment: @hehemath : really? It's only $(aX+bY)^2=a^2X^2+2abXY+b^2Y^2$

Comment: My god I'm so foolish. I see it now lol. Thanks.

Comment: I'm taking calculus I at the moment and I've been focusing on that, guess I forgot how to factorise 9th grade expressions lol.

Comment: @hehemath:  try the same proof with $(aX-bY)$ as an exercise.

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help. Checked the answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Be aware that: $$\mathsf{Var}(Z)=\mathsf{Cov}(Z,Z)\tag1$$

where by definition: $$\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathbb E(X-\mathbb EX)(Y-\mathbb EY)\tag2$$

Based on $(2)$ that we find that:

- $\mathsf{Cov}$ is symmetric in the sense that $\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)=\mathsf{Cov}(Y,X)$
- $\mathsf{Cov}(aX,Y)=a\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)$
- $\mathsf{Cov}(X+Z,Y)=\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)+\mathsf{Cov}(Z,Y)$

This together makes it possible to prove that $\mathsf{Cov}$ is **bilinear** so that:

- $\mathsf{Cov}(aX,aX)=a^2\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)$
- $\mathsf{Cov}(aX+bY,aX+bY)=a^2\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)+2ab\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)+b^2\mathsf{Cov}(Y,Y)$
- $\mathsf{Cov}(aX-bY,aX-bY)=a^2\mathsf{Cov}(X,X)-2ab\mathsf{Cov}(X,Y)+b^2\mathsf{Cov}(Y,Y)$

Now apply $(1)$ in those rules.